# Editing html stored in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im storing some html code in a mysql database . This code is then displayed on the page .

I have setup an editor where a user can edit the code and save it back to the database . This updates the page.

The problem im having is that when its updated , it deletes parts each time.

mysql:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE website_text SET home = '".$_POST['home']."'");
```

editor:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="home" id="home" value="<?php echo $data['home']; ?>" required></textarea>
```

Comment: Are you sure the field in your SQL table is set to `text` ?

Comment: you need a `where` clause, otherwise it will update EVERYTHING in your table

Comment: yh , the type is text . should the Collation be anything specific?

Comment: the value of a textarea should be between the tags, a textarea doesn't have a value attribute. e.g. `<textarea><?php echo $data['home']; ?></textarea>`

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

A textarea does not have a `value` property... You need to put the content of it in it:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="home" id="home" required><?php echo $data['home']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: true, but that's only 50% of the issue

Comment: True that, the other part requires more user input.

Comment: Thanks . Whats the other 50% of the issue?

Comment: @Jess [other 50%...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168348/editing-html-stored-in-mysql#comment48442865_30168348). Read up on UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: You update the `home` column for every record in the table. Unless you only have 1 record with a column for every page...

Comment: yh , its one record with each column representing a part of a page

Comment: In that case, this is valid (except for the possibility of SQL injection, XSS and such vulnarabilities). I wouldn't recommended working like this (what if you need more pages? A table altering is never recommended!), but your problem is solved... For now.